# Bootstrap non-responsive under 768px

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to use Bootstrap with responsiveness for different size of screen on computer. But I also need to don't be responsive under 768px.

Is there a way to do that ? To use that :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And in the same time, set the min-width of the viewport to 768px ?

Thanks.

Comment: Or just reset the media queries for widths < 768px ...

Comment: OK, how can I do that ?

Comment: Haven't tried but what about setting `body { min-width: 768px; }`?

Comment: I've just tried and it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

I may have the soultion for you. Not sure it works because never had the need to be not responsive in a certain resolution anyway you should try to load every CSS only when resolution is >768 and, otherwise, write a dedicated CSS file to load when you <768.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' **media='min-width: 768px'**/>
```

Now you are telling the browser to load this file only when the resolution is major than 768px

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='max-width: 767px'/>
```

And when the resolution is minor than 768 load this css file

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I don't think it fits my needs. Because with your solution, I need a css file of bootstrap for max-width 767px and it back to use / delete media queries.

Comment: you can write the style in your custom CSS. Maybe it would be more quick to find a solution if you tell us what you CAN and what you CANT do :)

Answer (score 0):

For disabling widths under 768px you need to edit the css, and delete the part where it says `@media (max-width: 768px)` and lower, e.g. `@media (max-width: 550px)`

Comment: Yes, I know but I can't edit bootstrap CSS file. It will be too easy, I need another solution.

Comment: I agree that is the most obvious way. However editing the original bootstrap.css file has its disadvantages. So you would need to copy and reset all media queries < 768px in the custom css-